# Not able to Access project folder through WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, database, wamp, backend

I am not able to get the click access to my project folder on WAMP server. I have tried the following solutions which were found online:

1. tried to change index.php by changing the $suppress_localhost variable, but in my file there is no such variable present.
2. tried changing httpd.conf file and that too didn't change the status of my problem.

Please See the image attached, to get a better idea(i hope the image is viewable).
Kindly guide me, as I am at a very beginner stage for backend coding.[my wamp server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZupnL.png)

Comment: What do you mean by “click access”?

Answer (score 0):

i cannot write a long and nice answer but check out this link [create a virtualhost](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,146746)
basically your project has to be in an Apache virtualhost in order to be displayed on the main page (that is what is said on your screenshot)